# Useful series for limit comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I already know the harmonic series ($1/n$, which diverges) and following the link, $1/n^2$ that converges.

What other useful series could you teach me, or perhaps some general advice? Any website/resource is very welcome also, since most of my search for them reveals only the harmonic one and not much more. (I know how to execute the test!).

Have a nice day!

Comment: Standard series for which convergence is known are: geometric series; $p$-series; any series that corresponds to an improper integral whose convergence you know; powers over factorials (e.g., $\frac{2^n}{n!}$), etc. The more series you figure out, the more you'll have in your portfolio to use for comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your share Arturo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the generalization of what you put above, the so called $p$-series.  Let $p\in \mathbb{R}$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$$ converges if and only if $p>1$.  This can be proven using the integral test mentioned by Shai Covo.

Also of interest are [alternating series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series), such as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ since there are good tests to see if they converge.  (The above sum converges) Specifically, the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) tells us that if we have a sequence $a_n$ with

(1) $a_n\cdot a_{n+1} <0$ for every $n$ (it alternates signs)

(2) $|a_{n+1}|\leq |a_n|$

(3) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n =0$

Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.  This then brings up the topic of [Conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) and [Absolute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) convergence.  For a generalization of the alternating series test, see [Dirichlets Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).  (This test allows us to give the conditions of convergence for series such as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin (n)$)

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

General advice: consider the [integral test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). As an exercise, apply it to the series $\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n(\log n)^\alpha  }}}$, $\alpha > 0$ fixed. For which $\alpha$ does the series coverge?

Another very useful test is the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). See also [convergence tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests).

Comment: Sorry to ruin your answer. We don't cover integral test in our course. :(